# How to achieve '.class1.class2' in CSS output with no space in between

Tags: less

In CSS '`.class1.class2`' with **no space between classes** means:

'*Select only those elements that have **AT LEAST** those 2 classes*';

How can I declare that in LESS?

What I am getting at is:

Class **featureCheckbox** is declared below ...

```
.featureCheckbox 
{
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

I wish to override '`width: 300px`' with '`width: 150px`' for elements that only have `class="featureCheckbox class2`" whilst picking up the other non-width rules associated with class `featureCheckbox`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&` to reference the current selector.

```
.featureCheckbox {
    // styles

    &.class2 {
        // overrides
    }
}
```

This will compile to:

```
.featureCheckbox {
    /* styles */
}
.featureCheckbox.class2 {
    /* overrides */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use & character for this as below:

```
.featureCheckbox{
    &.class2 {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less is backwards compatible to CSS, basic CSS selectors work identically in LESS.

Just write

```
.featureCheckbox.class2 {
...
```

like you would in CSS.